# Change position of a Flutter Snackbar

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, android-snackbar

I want to display a simple disappearing error message **above** a button when certain conditions aren't met. It seems as if Flutter's Snackbar is well suited to this purpose.

However, I'm having difficulty changing the position of the Snackbar to be anything other than at the very bottom of the screen. Is this possible? If not, is there a Widget better suited for this purpose?

My current snackbar code:

```
class ContinueButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
          bottom: 24.0, top: 24.0),
      child: Align(
        alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
        child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final snackBar = SnackBar(
              content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
            );
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
          },

          child: Text('Continue'),
          height: 40.0,
          minWidth: 300.0,
          color: Colors.greenAccent,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 25):

You can try by, setting behavior as **SnackBarBehavior.floating** and setting margin as much as you want.

```
SnackBar(
  behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100.0),
  content: Text("Hello World!"),
);
```

The only issue with this solution is that everything underneath **won't be clickable**.

To resolve this clickable issue, set dismissDirection property to DismissDirection.none. This also means that the default property of a snackbar being able to be dismissed by dragging it down is lost. (default is [DismissDirection.down](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBar/dismissDirection.html))

```
SnackBar(
  behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100.0),
  content: Text("Hello World!"),
  dismissDirection: DismissDirection.none
);
```

Comment: the only issue with this solution is that everything underneath will not be clickable

Comment: And that's a big problem...

Answer (score 7):

**You can do this by placing a container inside the snackbar**. Since snackbar can take any widget and you can change its background color to transparent, you can use a container with custom padding and borders to give an illusion of positioning.

```
SnackBar(content: Container(
  //color: Colors.white,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.black), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 75),
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
  ),
), backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, elevation: 1000, behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,);
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no. But you can use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html to display a Widget over another Widget (In your case over and above like a Tooltip widget) and create a Widget similar to Snackbar Widget

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't do that.

> [A lightweight message with an optional action which briefly displays at the bottom of the screen.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBar-class.html)

You can just change it's [behavior](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBar/behavior.html) and [elevation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBar/elevation.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Flushbar** instead of **SnackBar**

check it for more detail

[flushbar](https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar)

**Note:** It has been discontinued as on 2022

Comment: due the discontinuation you might want to check [another_flushbar](https://pub.dev/packages/another_flushbar)

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

You can wrap your container with 'Align'.

```
SnackBar(
    content: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        controller?.close();
      },
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Container( ........
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the SnackBar at the top of the screen too, and after a lot of searching, I finally found one here and will be sharing it in case anyone needs to add the SnackBar at the top too.

I did it like this:

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(
      showCloseIcon: true,
      closeIconColor: Colors.white,
      content: Text('your text', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      dismissDirection: DismissDirection.up,
      behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 70, left: 10, right: 10),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

An important note is that this SnackBar will be at the top of all screens, meaning the screen below will not be clickable, so you will have to wait for the SnackBar to disappear or close it. According to all my studies, I was unable to make the lower screen clickable with just the SnackBar in this position, it will only be possible with the package.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party but it's possible to use a ScaffoldMessenger to control the positioning. See https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger

Instead of using

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

You then wrap a Scaffold that you've positioned in your UI with a ScaffoldMesseneger and given it a key.  Use this key to then show the snackBar:

```
final key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
ScaffoldMessenger(
      key: key,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ...
...
key.currentState?.showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a margin only property to the SnackBar and set the top bottom value.

```
margin: EdgeInsets.only(
     bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 150,
  ),
```