# Flutter - How to position snackbar above system navigation bar

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview, flutter-getx

I have a transparent system navigation bar in my application.

[image]

Getx snack bar is used by the app to throw errors and success messages. What I'm stuck with is that anytime the app throws a snack bar, the snack bar appears and disappears through the transparent navigation bar (i can see the snack bar move through the navigation bar). Is there any way to have the snack bar appear above the navigation bar? How can I position the snack bar above the system navigation bar?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into [SnackBarBehavior](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBarBehavior.html) enum which allows one to change the position. If you are using a third party library then you may want to try putting the behavior into an extension method. Alternative ideas exist on this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267002/change-position-of-a-flutter-snackbar) that may apply in your use case although not an exact duplicate.

The SnackbarBehavior enum states:

> Defines where a SnackBar should appear within a Scaffold and how its location should be adjusted when the scaffold also includes a FloatingActionButton or a BottomNavigationBar.

Other ideas include using a position widget with a Stack widget to gain precise control. Add a MediaQuery or other fractional widgets to allow for multiple screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use SnackBar Widget that developed by flutter team instead of Getx snackbar. It basically appears above of navigation bar here an basic example;

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text('Show Snackbar'),
      onPressed: () {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: const Text('Awesome Snackbar!'),
              action: SnackBarAction(
                label: 'Action',
                onPressed: () {
                  // Code to execute.
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  static GetSnackBar SuccessSnackBar({String title = 'Success', String message}) {
    Get.log("[$title] $message");
    return GetSnackBar(
      titleText: Text(title.tr, style: Get.textTheme.headline6.merge(TextStyle(color: Get.theme.primaryColor))),
      messageText: Text(message, style: Get.textTheme.caption.merge(TextStyle(color: Get.theme.primaryColor))),
      snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle_outline, size: 32, color: Get.theme.primaryColor),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 18),
      borderRadius: 8,
      dismissDirection: DismissDirection.horizontal,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
    );
  }
```

Used like this in my app. Worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Get.snackbar(
          "Bruh",
          "Your quantity have to at least one",
          colorText: Colors.black,
          backgroundColor: Palette.yellowColor,
        );
```

In my case, this is my return to show snackbar for error message, the snackbar appear on top below the appbar

In the getx snackbar there are a snackPosition: attribute

You can use that to display yours

Comment: is there anything similar to snackbarbehavior in getx snackbar?. My app needs to show the snackbar at the bottom